# How to add / list / remove a group

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, permissions

How can I add a new group (for file permission)?

How can I view the full list of existing groups?

How can I remove a group?

I prefer to do the above using a UI rather than terminal commands if possible.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 10):

Which group do you belong to:

> groups

All existing groups are in the file /etc/group. You would need just the first column of each entry (the fields are separated by colons). Thus:

> cut -d: -f1 /etc/group

New groups are defined using

> groupadd groupname

Groups are removed using

> groupdel groupname